# Wait for two Observables then return a promise of a different Observable?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have two Observables of different types and what I would like to do is to wait for both to emit at least once then somehow immediately return a promise of a third Observable with yet another return type.

Right now I have this:

```
return Observable.forkJoin([$A, $B])
    .do(() => {
        return $C;
    })
    .toPromise()
    .then(result => result);
```

Where `$A` is an `Observable<AType>` and `$B` is an `Observable<BType>` but I don't care what those results are, I just want to know when they've completed. *Then* I want to return a `toPromise` of `$C` which would be a `Promise<CType>`.

For some reason this isn't working, I think it's returning a `Promise<Void[]>` or an `Observable<Void[][]>` or something like that but I'm not sure how to debug this. But I think I have the right idea because forkJoin seems to be "subscribing"/executing the first two promises and then I can see that it *is* waiting on both to resolve it's just the return type is wrong I think.

Comment: `.do` doesn't return anything -- it's just for tapping into an observable stream. I think you may just want to `.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost correct but the `do` operator just performs side-effects and it doesn't modify the chain at all.

Instead you should use `concatMap` (`mergeMap` will work as well) that waits until the inner Promise resolves and then returns it's value. You said you want to return a Promise so you'll still use `toPromise` anyway because this will turn the whole chain into a Promise:

```
return Observable.forkJoin([$A, $B])
    .concatMap(() => $C)
    .toPromise()
    .then(result => result);
```

**Edit:** What you mentioned about `mergeMap` and `concatMap` is correct but it's the `forkJoin` that does the most important logic. `forkJoin` will emit a single item (an array of the last emissions from each source Observable) after all source Observable complete. This means that it doesn't matter if you use `mergeMap` or `concatMap` because they receive a single value (an array) they ignore and just return the `$C` Promise.

Comment: Would `mergeMap` actually still wait for the for the first two Observables to resolve?

Comment: This is unrelated to neither `mergeMap` nor `concatMap`. The `forkJoin`  operator is responsible for waiting until both `$A` and `$B` emit at least one value and complete.

Comment: I'm just a little confused still. So (here)[https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html] I read about the difference of `mergeMap` which says `Because concatMap does not subscribe to the next observable until the previous completes, the value from the source delayed by 2000ms will be emitted first. Contrast this with mergeMap which subscribes immediately to inner observables...` so I understood that as `mergeMap` would be subscribed immediately to `forkJoin` and wouldn't wait for it to complete?

Answer (score 0):

`do` (or better, `tap`) is used to act on the observed data without interfering with the flow. It's returns the same observable it acts on.

You need to `map` your value to the new observable.